# Problems with istream& operator >>

Tags: c++, operators, cin, istream

I am still wondering about istream operator>>.
In my function `istream& operator >> (istream &is, Student& a)`, I didn't use `is` but still return it at the end of the function. I still get the correct answer with `cin >> a`. Can anyone explain why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Student() : age(0){}
    Student (int age1) : age(age1) {}
    void setAge();
    int getAge(){return age;}
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, Student& a);
};

istream& operator >> (istream &is, Student& a)
{
    a.setAge();
    return is;
}
void Student::setAge(){
    int age1;
    cout << "input age of the student: "<< endl;
    cin >> age1;
    age = age1;
}

int main()
{
    Student a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Age of Student is " << a.getAge() << "?";
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself what's the point of the `is` parameter to your operator if you're just going to hit `cin` in `setAge` anyway ? `setAge` should do just that: take an `int` parameter and set the `age` member. Leave how you get the value to pass in for that out of it.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine because you are calling

```
cin >> a;
```

If instead you did this

```
ifstream ifs ("test.txt", ifstream::in);
ifs >> a;
```

Then your program will read from standard input instead of the file (test.txt) like it's supposed to be doing.

The correct implementation would be

```
istream& operator >> (istream &is, Student& a)
{
    return is >> a.age;
}
```

Now if you call

```
cin >> a;
```

it would read from standard input

and if you call

```
ifs >> a;
```

it would read from the file.

Answer (score 2):

> In my function `istream& operator >> (istream &is, Student& a)`, I didn't use `is` but still return it at the end of the function. I still get the correct answer with `cin >> a`. Can anyone explain why?

Because `Student::setAge()` is accessing `cin` directly, which is the same stream that `is` happens to be pointing at in your example.

This is not the correct design.  A member setter should not be prompting the user for input.  You should prompt for input first, then pass the value to your setter afterwards.  The class should be agnostic about where its values are coming from.

Use something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Student() : age(0){}
    Student (int age1) : age(age1) {}
    void setAge(int value);
    int getAge(){return age;}
    void readFrom(istream& is);
};

istream& operator >> (istream &is, Student& a)
{
    a.readFrom(is);
    return is;
}

void Student::readFrom(istream& is){
    is >> age;
}

void Student::setAge(int value){
    age = value;
}

int main()
{
    Student a;
    int age;
    cout << "input age of the student: "<< endl;
    cin >> age;
    a.setAge(age);
    cout << "Age of Student is " << a.getAge() << "?";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are quite a few points to make in your example.

Firstly a setter should have a parameter. By convention, a *setter* always gets a parameter which alters the class and then the *getter* is parameterless and should be **const**.

Secondly, your implementation of setAge directly accesses std::cin. If you look at my example you will see that I do make use of the is parameter. That separates the setAge from the source of the parameter and allows for better OOD.

Thirdly, my implementation also provides better abstraction because the input stream is could be any stream (for example a file, or maybe a stream from the internet)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Student() : age(0){}
    Student(int age1) : age(age1) {}
    void setAge(int age1);
    int getAge() const { return age; }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, Student& a);
};

istream& operator >> (istream &is, Student& a)
{
    int age1;
    is >> age1;
    a.setAge(age1);
    return is;
}
void Student::setAge(int age1){
    age = age1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Student a;
    cout << "input age of the student: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Age of Student is " << a.getAge() << "?" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't use `is`

Yes you did. You just used it from a different function, is all.

It's the same stream because it's `cin` in both cases.

If you ever wanted to extract from a different stream then your code would be broken. This is why we prefer to use the argument to `operator>>` rather than sort of guessing at what it was (`cin`).